# Rename installed .deb with dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, package-management

Is there a way to rename an installed `.deb` package with `dpkg`?

Context: I have installed a library compiled for debug using [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall), now I wish to install the library compiled for release, for the release version I renamed the package `mypackage-release` and I would like to rename the debug package (currently know to dpkg as `mypackage`) to `mypackage-debug`.

Comment: The only thing worse than using checkinstall is modifying the resultant package willy nilly.

Comment: Can you comment on why you feel this way about these things PriceChild?

Comment: For starters, I don't see how you can work out dependencies effectively. Checkinstall 'sort of works' but I'd definitely advocate building your own debian package and doing it properly. It's a slog, but once you've done it once, updating it will be far more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Just Don't Do It.  And in the future, refrain from putting version and build information in the package name; you want something like `mypackage_1.0~debug` and `mypackage_1.0` instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Is the use of '~' a special naming convention I am unaware of?

Comment: The version numbering of `deb` packages has a special feature so you can create "prerelease" packages.  `packagename-1.0` is always regarded as newer than `packagename-1.0~anything` but they are the same package.  (If you need to be able to install both at the same time, then of course this doesn't make sense.  Create a separate `packagename-debug` package in that case, perhaps only containing the debug symbols for the main package.)  Normally, the sort order is such that any suffix is regarded as "newer" than a version string with no suffix.

Comment: I don't understand. "packagename-1.0 is always regarded as newer than packagename-1.0~anything" + "any suffix is regarded as "newer" than a version string with no suffix" ?

Comment: @andresp: Any suffix except one starting with a tilde is regarded as newer, but the tilde is a special case devised precisely for this scenario.